# I have problem in code sentiment analysis bert bgru with multichannel cnn

Tags: python

I have errors in the following code, i tried many time to solve it but i cant that.
please help me.

I was facing error number 1, so I made some adjustments, and now I am facing error number 2
1)InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
2) ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((128, 1) vs (64, 1)).

i used code sentiment analysis bert bgru with multichannel CNN, but I faced errors.

I had a problem putting the code here, so if there is someone who will help me solve the problem, I will send the code to him, thank you for your cooperation in advance

""

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained: what issue specifically kept you from adding the code to your question? If you're not sure how to format code in the Question Builder, there are some helpful guidelines here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks